# Navigation error when trying to segue back to first view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting this error when exiting the second view controller: "UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly." I'm Not sure what is going on.

**View Controller 1:**

```
   class ViewController1: UIViewController {

var getVal:String = "val"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    label1.text = getVal
}

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!



@IBAction func unwindSegue(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    print(getVal)
 }
}
```

**View Controller 2:**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

var cheese:String = "American"

@IBAction func changeVar(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    cheese = "Swiss"
    print(cheese)
}


   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController1
   
   vc.getVal = cheese
    
 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking away "sender: Any?" from the unwind segue eliminated the error. According to the "Develop in Swift Fundamentals" e-book, "You can name the method (i.e. the unwind segue) anything you like, but it must take **UIStoryBoard** as it's **only** parameter."

**Before:**

```
@IBAction func unwindSegue(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:            Any?) {
}
```

**After**:

```
@IBAction func unwindSegue(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```